# How to bring JavaFX Popup to front when focused?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, javafx-11

I have some JavaFX `Popup` in my application. And when any of these popups is foucsed, I need it bring on top of every other popups regardless of it's index in `Window.getWindows()`.

I've tried to call method like `toFront` but it's not in `Popup` class. I've also tried to change index of focused `Popup` in `Window.getWindows()` but that also didn't worked because I don't know how to interchange index of two elements in a `ObservableList`.

**e.g.**

Let's say I have two `Popup` called `p1` and `p2` and in each I have nodes `n1` and `n2` respectively which are used to move these popup, So whenever `n1` is dragged `p1` should come on top and when `n2` is dragged `p2` should come on top.

Here is my minimal example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Popup;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Example extends Application{
    
    public static void main(String... arguments){
        
        launch(arguments);
    }
    
    public void applyTo(Pane node, Popup parent){
        
        final double[] dragDelta = new double[2];
        
        node.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
            dragDelta[0] = parent.getX() - e.getScreenX();
            dragDelta[1] = parent.getY() - e.getScreenY();
            //code to bring parent Popup to front
        });
        
        node.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
            parent.setX(e.getScreenX() + dragDelta[0]);
            parent.setY(e.getScreenY() + dragDelta[1]);
        });
    }
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        
        Button b1 = new Button("Open p1");
        Button b2 = new Button("Open p2");
        
        HBox n1 = new HBox(new Label("This is p1"));
        HBox n2 = new HBox(new Label("This is p2"));
        n1.setMinSize(200, 120);
        n2.setMinSize(200, 120);
        n1.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue; -fx-background-radius: 4px;");
        n2.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red; -fx-background-radius: 4px;");
        n1.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        n2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        
        Popup p1 = new Popup();
        Popup p2 = new Popup();
        p1.getContent().add(n1);
        p2.getContent().add(n2);
        
        applyTo(n1, p1);
        applyTo(n2, p2);
        
        b1.setOnAction(event -> {
            if(!p1.isShowing()) p1.show(primaryStage);
            else p1.hide();
        });
        b2.setOnAction(event -> {
            if(!p2.isShowing()) p2.show(primaryStage);
            else p2.hide();
        });
        
        HBox root = new HBox(10, b1, b2);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 500, 200));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    
}
```

So what is the solution for this problem?

Comment: Check this: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8123137

Comment: @nicomp , I've asked how to bring any popup to front when there are many popups not how to focus/unfocus because if I want to check whether a popup is focused or not, I'll add a mouse pressed event to the node I'm using  in a popup to make a popup movable. i.e. focus is not the problem here.

Comment: setAlwaysOnTop() ?

Comment: @nicomp `setAlwaysOnTop() ` is also not available for `Popup`

Comment: You call it for the stage containing the popup.

Comment: @nicomp I have more than one `Popup` in a same single `Stage`.

Comment: I think you've answered your own question. You need more stages.

Comment: @nicomp No sir! It is absolutely valid to use more than one popup in a same stage. Because in this case, It would be so ridiculous to make 10-12 stages only because I want to use these many Popups.

Comment: I didn't say your code wasn't valid. I pointed out a fix for your problem and a way to make the fix work for you. The decision to implement is up to you. I would disagree about the 'ridiculous' characterization. Sometimes we gotta do what we gotta do.

Comment: No prob, I suspect JavaFX annoys me as much as it does you. :)

Comment: if you say so, then solve it yourself *shrugs .. always wondering about the attitude of some askers: you want help on unsupported functionality (which might be possible or not, don't know without coding), you don't know how to do it yourself, but are arrogant enough to know what is needed. If you are so far as knowing that for sure, then you must be able to solve it on your own. And you can't be bothered to at least provide the most minimal example to demonstrate what you are after and what didn't work out and ... *head-shaking

Comment: @kleopatra Respectfully, I've already did provided example according to my knowledge. And No one knows everything, If you think you know more than someone who is asking a question(Of very low level, in your opinion) than I cannot do anything about your view about this question!

Comment: sure you can - replace those snippets with an [mcve] ;)

Comment: @kleopatra see recent edit I've improved my example and I think this should be what one could say, an Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example :)

Comment: yeah, looks good :) will try tomorrow or so ...

Comment: What's the reason to using many popups? That doesn't seem standard behaviour. One popup at a time is better UI design, otherwise the user gets confused (and the programmer gets trouble).

Comment: @PerdiEstaquel Well, I'm trying to create something [like this](https://astutegraphics.com/images/blog/tutorials/custom_tool_panel_22_jan_2014/01.png) and I guess these all are popups in Illustrator cc

Comment: Ok, I guess the terminology is the problem here: those are not popups, they're plain flat panes, or windows without borders. A popup pops-up, and those in your screenshot don't.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason I don't understand, toFront/back is only implemented on Stage, not on its parent classes even though the actual collaborator that manages the stacking is already available in Window:

The implementation in Stage:

```
/**
 * Bring the {@code Window} to the foreground.  If the {@code Window} is
 * already in the foreground there is no visible difference.
 */
public void toFront() {
    if (getPeer() != null) {
        getPeer().toFront();
    }
}
```

`getPeer()` is a package-private method in Window that returns the internal class TKStage. So if you are allowed to go dirty (because accessing an internal class and having to access via reflection - all with the usual loud "Beware"!) would be:

```
protected void toFront(Popup popup) {
    // use your favorite utility method to invoke a method  
    TKStage peer = (TKStage) FXUtils.invokeGetMethodValue(Window.class, popup, "getPeer");
    if (peer != null) {
        peer.toFront();
    }
}
```

Requires to export/open not-exported packages in javafx.graphics - compiler and runtime errors will guide you (my context is heavily tweaked anyway, so don't know exactly which are added by this)

Comment: How can I use TKStage in Module based project?

Comment: you have to --add-exports and --add-opens as the error messages tell you, just translate it one-by-one until all are gone ;)

Comment: I added `Method m = popup.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getPeer");` and `m.setAccessible(true);` but it gives error `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: javafx.stage.Popup.getPeer()`, Please help

Comment: the method is declared in Window - you need to read the sources if you want to go dirty :-)

Comment: I've read the source of Window and Popup and I've tried `Method m = Window.class.getDeclaredMethod("getPeer");` and `m.setAccessible(true);` it give error that javafx.graphcs does not opens javafx.stage so I added `--add-opens=javafx.graphics/javafx.stage=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED` but opens error is still not removed

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution with stages it is the only work around I have found at all even though you hate the idea of having multiple stages if you want the functionality this is it. If you decide to stick with leaving them in the background thats cool too. An idea to solve your too may stages dilemma is to use a queue of stages remove when in use and if all are shown add a new one when a stage is hidden send to the end of the queue

```
public class Example extends Application {


    public void applyTo(Pane node, Stage parent, Stage primaryStage){

        final double[] dragDelta = new double[2];

        node.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
            dragDelta[0] = parent.getX() - e.getScreenX();
            dragDelta[1] = parent.getY() - e.getScreenY();
            //code to bring parent Popup to front
        });

        node.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
            parent.setX(e.getScreenX() + dragDelta[0]);
            parent.setY(e.getScreenY() + dragDelta[1]);
            primaryStage.requestFocus();
        });

        node.setOnMouseReleased(event -> {
            primaryStage.requestFocus();
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

        Button b1 = new Button("Open p1");
        Button b2 = new Button("Open p2");

        HBox n1 = new HBox(new Label("This is p1"));
        HBox n2 = new HBox(new Label("This is p2"));
        n1.setMinSize(200, 120);
        n2.setMinSize(200, 120);
        n1.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue; -fx-background-radius: 4px;");
        n2.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red; -fx-background-radius: 4px;");
        n1.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        n2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Stage p1 = new Stage(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        Stage p2 = new Stage(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        p1.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        p2.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        p1.setScene(new Scene(n1));
        p2.setScene(new Scene(n2));

        applyTo(n1, p1, primaryStage);
        applyTo(n2, p2, primaryStage);

        b1.setOnAction(event -> {
            if(!p1.isShowing()) {
                p1.show();
                primaryStage.requestFocus();
            }
            else
                p1.hide();
        });

        b2.setOnAction(event -> {
            if(!p2.isShowing()) {
                p2.show();
                primaryStage.requestFocus();
            }
            else
                p2.hide();
        });



        HBox root = new HBox(10, b1, b2);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 500, 200));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }

}
```

Comment: There is another problem in this approach that I was avoiding that is, when other stages are focused the primary stage loses focus. so, this is not the solution to my problem :(

Comment: Problem that I mentioned In first comment still remains. And since it's the nature of a `Stage` that whenever focused it comes to front so even without `parent.toFront();` this program will act the same way.

Comment: So you want the the primary stage focused at all times? Then you can't see the popups

Comment: yes and also always at bottom of everything else that's why I used `Popup`

Comment: You can solve that by adding `.setAlwaysOnTop(true);` to keep the focus on your application but have the windows shown on top

Comment: I think that you cannot achieve your idea, the "Popup" components seems to be very simple and you always will have the last popup at top. The use of stages is the unique option so this answer with maybe some updates is the unique option to achieve something like that. Also you cannot have the focus on your main stage and a popup at the same time. You can remove the background of stage if you want to use background radius with setFill to transparent and use initModality and initOwner to work as internal window.